# Execute a piece of code when Kotlin channel becomes full

Tags: kotlin, channel, kotlin-coroutines

I'd like to write a simple batch processor class. It has a request queue and waits this queue to become full or some amount of time to be passed and only then talks to a database.

It is very convenient to implement this queue via channel - so that our clients will be suspended while it is full. But how can I find out if the channel becomes full?

Of course I can create a method that sends something to the channel and then performs some checks. The next step is to encapculate it in a class derived from Channel. Still very dirty (and it's unclear how can I handle `onSend`/`onReceive`). Are there any more elegant solutins? Maybe something out-of-box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is nothing out-of-the box, but the corresponding batching logic can be readily implemented using an actor. You don't really need a class for that (but you wrap this code in a class if you wish). You can use the following implementation as a template:

```
const val MAX_SIZE = 100 // max number of data items in batch
const val MAX_TIME = 1000 // max time (in ms) to wait

val batchActor = actor<Data> {
    val batch = mutableListOf<Data>()
    var deadline = 0L // deadline for sending this batch to DB
    while (true) {
        // when deadline is reached or size is exceeded, then force batch to DB
        val remainingTime = deadline - System.currentTimeMillis()
        if (batch.isNotEmpty() && remainingTime <= 0 || batch.size >= MAX_SIZE) {
            saveToDB(batch)
            batch.clear()
            continue
        }
        // wait until items is received or timeout reached
        select<Unit> {
            // when received -> add to batch
            channel.onReceive {
                batch.add(it)
                // init deadline on first item added to batch
                if (batch.size == 1) deadline = System.currentTimeMillis() + MAX_TIME
            }
            // when timeout is reached just finish select, note: no timeout when batch is empty
            if (batch.isNotEmpty()) onTimeout(remainingTime) {}
        }
    }
}
```

Now you just do `batchActor.send(data)` whenever you need to send anything to the database and the logic inside the actor takes care about batching and saving the resulting batches to the database.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! Surely must accept it. Though the code looks pretty imperative

Answer (score 0):

The Channel Interface declares an isFull property which can be queried to determine if it has reached capacity.

I can't see anyway to have a callback function to automatically invoke a function when the capacity is reached but you could periodically check this isFull property to see if it is at capacity.