# How to read all available elements from a Channel in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I would like to read all available elements from a channel so that I can do batch processing on them if my receiver is slower then my sender (in hopes that processing a batch will be more performant and allow the receiver to catch up). I only want to suspend if the channel is empty, not suspend until my batch is full or timeout unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798510/execute-a-piece-of-code-when-kotlin-channel-becomes-full).

Is there anything built into the standard kotlin library to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4):

I did not find anything in the standard kotlin library, but here is what I came up with. This will suspend only for the first element and then `poll` all remaining elements. This only really works with a [Buffered Channel](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/coroutines-guide.md#buffered-channels) so that elements ready for processing are queued and available for `poll`

```
/**
 * Receive all available elements up to [max]. Suspends for the first element if the channel is empty
 */
internal suspend fun <E> ReceiveChannel<E>.receiveAvailable(max: Int): List<E> {
    if (max <= 0) {
        return emptyList()
    }

    val batch = mutableListOf<E>()
    if (this.isEmpty) {
        // suspend until the next message is ready
        batch.add(receive())
    }

    fun pollUntilMax() = if (batch.size >= max) null else poll()

    // consume all other messages that are ready
    var next = pollUntilMax()
    while (next != null) {
        batch.add(next)
        next = pollUntilMax()
    }

    return batch
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I tested Jakes code and it worked well for me (thanks!). Without max limit, I got it down to:

```
suspend fun <E> ReceiveChannel<E>.receiveAvailable(): List<E> {
    val allMessages = mutableListOf<E>()
    allMessages.add(receive())
    var next = poll()
    while (next != null) {
        allMessages.add(next)
        next = poll()
    }
    return allMessages
}
```